# remove existing spam comments

Tags: comments, advertising

I have a Drupal 7 site. This is a live site with both legitimate comments and spam comments. From what I can tell, most of the spam modules work when a comment is submitted, but don't go back and look at existing comments, comments added prior to the module being installed. I'm looking for a way to do this programmatically.

Comment: Recaptcha is good enough to catch such spam comments.

Comment: @AgA  Can the reCAPTCHA module run tests on comments that have actually made it into the database?

Comment: Is will not be needed in my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) has an "Unpublish comments containing keyword" operation.

[image]